# How to pass user-defined properties to Javascript object that may not exist yet?

Tags: javascript

I have a global object, `SomeObj` (using a revealing module pattern), defined in `//url/to/js/file.js`
`SomeObj` contains two setter methods: `SomeObj.setX()` and `SomeObj.setY()` that internally  sets some private variables (X and Y) on `SomebObj`.  There is no way to access private variables X and Y except through these set methods that I've exposed via the revealing module pattern.

I have another method called `SomeObj.render()` that uses the X and Y variables.

So, here's the scenario.  Another developer is going to be invoking `SomeObj.render()` within a third-party callback function.

```
function thirdPartyCallbackFunction() {
    $.getScript("//url/to/js/file.js", function() {
         SomeObj.render();
    });
}
```

This code is in a proprietary CMS. However, in the use case, our users are supposed to have the ability to be able to call `SomeObj.setX()` and `SomeObj.setY()` to set the variables that `SomeObj.render()` needs.  However, due to the way the CMS was designed, the user does not have access to modify the content area that `function thirdPartyCallbackFunction()` resides.

In fact, the content area where `SomeObj.setX()` and `SomeObj.setY()` can be called may be positioned before or after `function thirdPartyCallbackFunction()`.  If the content area is before `function thirdPartyCallbackFunction()`, `SomeObj` is not defined yet and an error will occur.

Is there a way to call `.setX()` and `.setY()` before `SomeObj` is defined?  Or is there another approach I should employ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how the code is laid out physically. All that matters is that you call `setX` and `setY` before you call `thirdPartyCallbackFunction`.

Comment: Your answer is obvious but not helpful.  I'm looking for a suggestion on how to do this given my situation.  The end user has complete control over the content areas.  I was trying to provide a structure/syntax for the end user that would guarantee that setX and setY would be called before the function regardless of where this content area is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave Serendipity the credit for the answer.  Based on Serendipity's answer about using global variables, I decided to create a global function declaration instead.

```
function configureSomeObj() {
  SomeObj.setX();
  SomeObj.setY();
}
```

Even though SomeObj may not be defined yet when this function is read, this function isn't fully evaluated until it is called.

I adjusted the third-party callback to this:

```
function thirdPartyCallbackFunction() {
    $.getScript("//url/to/js/file.js", function() {
        configureSomeObj();
        SomeObj.render();
    });
}
```

Now, `configreSomeObj()` can be anywhere on the page, before or after `thirdPartyCallbackFunction()`.  This does introduce a global function, but the code inside of it is organized.

Comment: I find this is a better answer BTW.

Comment: It's good to hear that my solution is reasonable.  I wouldn't have thought of this right away (if at all!) if you didn't provide your answer to kickstart my brain. :)

Comment: I think you should really mark this as the right answer. Useful for those who may have a similar problem in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the vote of confidence in my answer.  I have to wait a few hours before I can mark my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have absolutely no way of controlling the CMS output, maybe the following might help.

Set your "X" and "Y" variables within the window object.

```
window.MyArguments = {};
window.MyArguments.X = 'whatever_is_x';
window.MyArguments.Y = 'whatever_is_y';
```

Once your callback executes, if "MyArguments" exists, you can update the values and call render.

```
function render() {
    if(window.MyArguments && window.MyArguments.X && window.MyArguments.Y) {
        SomeObj.setX(window.MyArguments.X);
        SomeObj.setY(window.MyArguments.Y);
        SomeObj.render();
    } else {
      //Set a time-out and call the same function again.
    }
}
```

And you can call this new "render" function within your callback.

```
function thirdPartyCallbackFunction() {
    $.getScript("//url/to/js/file.js", function() {
         render();
    });
}
```

You can also try the opposite, where you check if SomeObj is available before calling methods on it and then set a timeout if it isn't available yet.

There is also an option of "sealing" and "unsealing" the pattern to allow partial updates to the definition of your Module.

Comment: Thanks for this idea.  I gave you credit, but I actually created a function declaration and dumped my object properties in there.  See my answer.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. where's your answer?

Comment: Hi Serendipity, it should be posted as an answer after yours.  Refresh the page.  You must have looked at my comment while I was writing out the answer.  I wasn't expecting you to respond to my comment so quickly!